# MySQL update an item of a nested set

Tags: mysql, nested-sets

I have a table in my database which conains a nested set of items, with significant columns being `id` and `parent`. `parent` always points to the row id it is nested within.

When I delete an item, its direct children start pointing to a nonexistent parent, which is something I'd like to correct.

I have tried this query in order to reset the parent of any orphaned items:

```
UPDATE menu_item
SET parent = 0
WHERE parent NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM menu_item
);
```

However, it gives me an error: "You can't specify target table 'menu_item' for update in FROM clause."

What is the correct way to tackle this?

Comment: It's not a nested sets, it's adjacency list.

Comment: Actually, I'm using a nested set, but the `left` and `right` columns are not relevant in my problem.

Comment: ah, OK. Do your parents refer to immediate parents or to ultimate ancestors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  mytable m
LEFT JOIN
        mytable mm
ON      mm.id = m.parent
SET     m.parent = 0
WHERE   mm.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't thought about using a join in my update query. It works perfectly :).

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
update m
set parent = 0
from menu_item m
where m.parent not in (select id from menu_item m1);
```

Comment: Your syntax is not valid, but thanks for giving it a shot :).